# Prezi HTML 5 & html5 book recommendation

Tags: javascript, html5, flash

I was wondering what were you thought on being able to build an app similar to prezi (presentation app) using HTML 5.

Also while you're at it, I'm looking for a good HTML 5 book recommendation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Some work already being done on alternatives, all SVG-based:

- [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/en:welcome)
- [Dizzy](http://dizzy.metafnord.org/)
- [JessyInk](http://code.google.com/p/jessyink/)

I'll leave it to you to decide whether SVG [counts](http://www.w3.org/html/logo/) as "HTML5"...

There's now the recently-released [impress.js](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js), which is obviously Javascript-based.

Comment: these are pretty cool too! I like the concepts. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Prezi is written in Flash/ActionScript, but there's no reason you couldn't attempt something similar with HTML/JavaScript. (Note that you won't be able to create an application like Prezi with HTML5 alone. You **will** need JavaScript too.)

Here are my favourite books on both subjects:

#### HTML5 books

- [*Introducing HTML5*](http://introducinghtml5.com/)
  by Bruce Lawson and Remy Sharp.
- [*HTML 5 for Web Designers*](http://www.abookapart.com/products/html5-for-web-designers)
  by Jeremy Keith.

#### JavaScript books

- [*Eloquent JavaScript*](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) by Marijn Haverbeke.
- [*JavaScript: The Good Parts*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748) by Douglas Crockford.
- [*jQuery: Novice to Ninja*](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/) by Earle Castledine & Craig Sharkie.
- [*jQuery in Action (2nd edition)*](http://www.manning.com/bibeault2/) by Bear Bibeault and Yehuda Katz.